# Using CoreBluetooth in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-bluetooth

I'm preparing implement app for bluetooth LE. But I still not understand it clearly. I have any questions about it. Could you please help me explain:

1. What's central and Peripherals mode?
2. I downloaded many source code about Bluetooth and see them implement 2 mode : Central and Peripheral mode. Why does it need implement both modes? I think if only need build application for scanning and get data from other device, it only need implement Central mode, is it right ?
3. What's UUID? And why it need when implement Peripherals mode?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This link may help Concept of BLE communication with iOS http://weblog.invasivecode.com/post/39707371281/core-bluetooth-for-ios-6-core-bluetooth-was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peripheral mode means that the device will act as a 'beacon': it will advertise its presence to application instances that are within its signal range.

As for the UUID, that is a unique code that each device has. Why? So you know which device you are talking to. So, for instance, if a store like Home Depot installs beacons, each one has a unique ID. When the app comes near them, it reads the ID and knows where you are so it can load the appropriate content.

You don't have to worry about Peripheral mode in iOS: it supports it. You can test this now even using another iOS device. So all you have to do is put a copy of your program on one phone and turn it on to be a beacon and then make the other one the receiver. Apple has an example app you can run. And you should watch the WWDC session on CoreBluetooth. Took me < 1h to get an example running that had one device advertising itself to the other.

Here is one of the examples: [BLTE Central Peripheral Example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012927)

This shows the 2 modes.

Comment: thanks Rod, it's helpful. I'll wait for your example. Thanks much

Comment: Rob. Post other questions as they come up.